# View visibility state loss when resuming activity with previously started Activity transition

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Explanation:

- I start an Activity B with an Activity transition from Activity A.
- After starting the new Activity B, I change visibility states of some views (`View.GONE`) in B.

The issue is:

When starting a new Activity C and going back to Activity B (or forcing an onPause in B), the views with the changed visibility states appearing again, without any touch of the views by code or else.

The following video explains the issue in pictures: https://youtu.be/oqCZo5CSkQk

When using no transition, everything works as expected. Has anybody an idea, how to prevent the view state loss when resuming the Activity? Do i use the `ActivityOptionsCompat` wrong?

I use the support libraries:

`'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'` and
`'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

But the issue also appears for older versions and on different phone manufactures (Pixel, Samsung, etc.).

Here the code for reproducing the issues:

**Layouts**

Activity A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="24dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Activity A | this starts the transition to another activity"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageToAnimate"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/star_big_on"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/start_next_activity"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
      android:text="start Another Activity"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <TextView
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="24dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Activity B | with progressbar"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageToAnimate"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:transitionName="toAnimate"
      app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/star_big_on"/>

  <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progress"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
      android:visibility="gone"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dismiss_text"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
      android:text="Also a text to dismiss"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/show"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="SHOW"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/hide_gone"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="SET GONE"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/hide_invisible"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="SET INVISIBLE"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/start_activity_c"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="START activity"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Activity C:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
      style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Activity C"
      android:textSize="40sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity source code**

Activity A:

```
public class DebugActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
        findViewById(R.id.start_next_activity).setOnClickListener(v -> startWithTransition());
    }

    private void startWithTransition() {
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
                .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(DebugActivityA.this,
                                              findViewById(R.id.imageToAnimate),
                                              "toAnimate");
        startActivity(new Intent(DebugActivityA.this, DebugActivityB.class), options.toBundle());
    }

}
```

Activity B:

```
public class DebugActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        View progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        View dismissText = findViewById(R.id.dismiss_text);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.show).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dismissText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });
        findViewById(R.id.hide_gone).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dismissText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });
        findViewById(R.id.hide_invisible).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            dismissText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        });
        findViewById(R.id.start_activity_c).setOnClickListener(this::startOtherActivity);
    }

    private void startOtherActivity(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, DebugActivityC.class));
    }

}
```

Activity C:

```
public class DebugActivityC extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you found a bug in Android. It seems like Android is forcing a layout state they saved (behind the scenes) for the shared element transition to work. And when your Activity B restarts, they don't care about the *real* layout state, they force what they previously saved, so the exit animation of Activity B will work. At list that's how it looks like... :)

Comment: Are you sure `onDestroy` is not called? In some cases it can.

Comment: Can you share your manifest file too?

Comment: @Kenny Seyffarth did you get any chance to look at the observation I mentioned in answer post ?

Comment: I think you should use for Start the Activity `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)` and for Receive the Result `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` in Activity B

Comment: thanks all for your responses, but this should not be a way to go solutions (also thanks @Krishna Sharma). The activity transition should work without any workarounds to keep views hidden. However, its a bug deep in the library, but will not be considered by the android team, so here mentioned in my filed bugticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112158868

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a feedback for this old question by me.

I filed a bugticket to google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112158868, but they are not able to fix this, since they prioritize other bugs.

My solution is here is to switch to a single activity concept with jetpack navigation (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation).

So i do the transitions with fragments now.

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSaveInstanceState` method to save the state of the UI when you leave the activity, then use `onRestoreInstanceState` to restore it back to that state.
Add `onSaveInstanceState` to Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putInt("progressbarVisibility", progressbar.getVisibility());
  savedInstanceState.putInt("dismissTextVisibility", dismissText.getVisibility());
}
```

And then add modify `onCreate` method of Activity B:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_play);

    View progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
    View dismissText = findViewById(R.id.dismiss_text);
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        dismissText.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("dismissTextVisibility", View.VISIBLE));
        progressbar.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("progressbarVisibility", View.VISIBLE)); 
    }
    // The rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: I don't re-create the activity in my case. I simple resume the activity (step back on Activity stack or resuming it after chosing the app in the task manager). So onCreate with the savedInstanceState will not be called.

Comment: @KennySeyffarth did you found any solution?

Comment: i have no solution at all for this, i filed a bug ticket to google, but they `may not be able to handle this bug` because of higher priority tickets.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112158868

Anyway, solution for me was to change to single activity concept with fragments, so the issue will not appear for me here anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a work around for this.

Rather than changing the views visibility in `onCreate`, which will only get called when `Activity` is newly created, try manipulating visibility of the Views in `onResume` based on flags in `Activity B` itself.

> Either use `SharedPreference` or even based on simple boolean flags

Now when `Activity B` is coming back to visibility, the same state will be re-applied based on these flags itself from `onResume`.

If using `SharedPreference`, then update new value while pushing new `Activity C`.

In `onResume` , check the value and alter your targeted Views.
Clear of the flag once `Activity B` is removed from backstack ie( `onDestroy` of `Activity B`)

Answer (score 0):

> It might or might not be a Shared transition library issue, I came up
>   with below approach to fix the visibility issue. Almost spent a day !!

Let me share my observation here.

***Such issue won't exist if you change the visibility state of shared transition views.***

If you have such requirement where you want to change the visibility of some views while using Shared transition, make them as shared view.

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(<view>, <uniqueString>);
```

Hereby sharing modified files, **I have verified and it solves our issue**.

**ActivityA**

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View startNextActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
        startNextActivity = findViewById(R.id.start_next_activity);
        startNextActivity.setOnClickListener(v -> startWithTransition());
    }

    private void startWithTransition() {
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
                .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                        new Pair<View, String>(startNextActivity, ActivityB.VIEW_NAME_IMAGEVIEW)
                        new Pair<View, String>(startNextActivity, ActivityB.VIEW_NAME_PROGRESSBAR),
                        new Pair<View, String>(startNextActivity, ActivityB.VIEW_NAME_DETAIL_TEXTVIEW));
        startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class), options.toBundle());
    }

}
```

**ActivityB**

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String VIEW_NAME_PROGRESSBAR = "progressbar";
    public static final String VIEW_NAME_IMAGEVIEW = "toAnimate";
    public static final String VIEW_NAME_DETAIL_TEXTVIEW = "detailTextView";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        View progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        View dismissText = findViewById(R.id.dismiss_text);
        View animateView = findViewById(R.id.imageToAnimate);

        // Key lines to fix our issue
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(animateView, VIEW_NAME_IMAGEVIEW);
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(progressbar, VIEW_NAME_PROGRESSBAR);
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(dismissText, VIEW_NAME_DETAIL_TEXTVIEW);

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.show).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dismissText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });
        findViewById(R.id.hide_gone).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dismissText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });
        findViewById(R.id.hide_invisible).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            dismissText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        });
        findViewById(R.id.start_activity_c).setOnClickListener(this::startOtherActivity);
    }

    private void startOtherActivity(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class));
    }

}
```

Hope it may help you somehow.

Have a nice day !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes..
Now is the time you can use **onSaveInstanceState** and **onRestoreInstanceState**.

You can Saved your visblity state in onSaveInstanceState **state** and restore **onRestoreInstanceState**. Activity always calls onSaveInstanceState & onRestoreInstanceState that work perfectly.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you start activity C and return, the XML of activity B is redrawn, so the default values that are VIEW.Visible are used. Subsequently, the views pop back again (appear).

You need to somehow save the view's state. Try:

- savedInstanceState or
- SharedPreferences